# Pandas.DataFrame: find the index of the row whose value in a given column is closest to (but below) a specified value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a Pandas.DataFrame, I would like to find the index of the row whose value in a given column is closest to (but below) a specified value. Specifically, say I am given the number 40 and the DataFrame df:

```
|    |   x |
|---:|----:|
|  0 |  11 |
|  1 |  15 |
|  2 |  17 |
|  3 |  25 |
|  4 |  54 |
```

I want to find the index of the row such that df["x"] is lower but as close as possible to 40. Here, the answer would be 3 because df[3,'x']=25 is smaller than the given number 40 but closest to it.
My dataframe has other columns, but I can assume that the column "x" is increasing.

For an exact match, I did (correct me if there is a better method):

```
    list = df[(df.x == number)].index.tolist()
    if list:
        result = list[0]
```

But for the general case, I do not know how to do it in a "vectorized" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter rows below 40 by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and get mximal index value by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
a = df.loc[df['x'].lt(40), 'x'].idxmax()
print (a)
3
```

---

For improve performance is possible use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `np.max`, solution working if default index:

```
a = np.max(np.where(df['x'].lt(40))[0])
print (a)
3
```

If not default `RangeIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[11,15,17,25,54]}, index=list('abcde'))

a = np.max(np.where(df['x'].lt(40))[0])
print (a)
3

print (df.index[a])
d
```

Comment: I'm guessing that "default index" means that index is range(len(df))? Thanks for the particular attention to performance.

Comment: @user0 - exactly, it is default `RangeIndex`

Comment: we could use `reset_index` in this case @user0

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

```
import pandas as pd

data  = {'x':[0,1,2,3,4,20,50]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#get df with selected condition
sub_df = df[df['x'] <= 40]

#get the idx of the maximum
idx = sub_df.idxmax()

print(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to `mask` greater or equal than `n`, then use [`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) to obtain 
the closest one:

```
n=40
val = df['x'].where(df['x'].lt(n)).idxmax()
print(val)
3
```

We could also use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['x'].mask(df['x'].ge(40)).idxmax()
```

or [`callable`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-callable) with [`loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df['x'].loc[lambda x: x.lt(40)].idxmax()
#alternative
#df.loc[lambda col: col['x'].lt(40),'x'].idxmax()
```

---

**If not by default `RangeIndex`**

```
i = df.loc[lambda col: col['x'].lt(40),'x'].reset_index(drop=True).idxmax()
df.index[i]
```

Comment: It is not the same solution, but okey....
you took `idxmax` from my answer @jezrael

Comment: something missing?